# Checking the result of this JSON response

Tags: json, ajax

this is returned from my mandrill api call:

```
[{email: "emai@hotmail.co.uk", status: "sent", _id: "8369b289ce2145d9b6272eae68593dfd",…}]
0: {email: "email@hotmail.co.uk", status: "sent", _id: "8369b289ce2145d9b6272eae68593dfd",…}
```

I want to be able to do a check in my ajax call like normal:

```
response.status
```

but I cant seem to get out the status part of the return, always is undefined.

Comment: if your response is `array` of single object. try like this `response[0].status`

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja thats what i thought, but still undefined

Comment: Can you show the actual `json` response you are getting?